# xamarin live player visualization error target of add is null

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms

I am trying to build my xamarin forms app for iOS and Android using Xamarin Live Player. I am getting `Visualization Error: Target of Add is null (NullReferenceException)` ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTDag.jpg)).

How to fix it?

Comment: Please post the code that is causing the error and the complete error message.

Comment: @RoiDanton I posted image of error. I don't have any errors in compilator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same error when I'm using Caresoul. I think that you are trying to use some code which not supported by Live Player.

Live player has some limitations, for example :

- Third party MVVM frameworks are not supported.
- Asset Catalogs on iOS are not supported.

[This link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/live-player/limitations?tabs=ios) will give you more information about live player limitations.

Comment: the only library I use is Newtonsoft.Json. How can I replace it? I don't have mac for iOS development.